# Transition from Computer Science to Statistics

Tags: graduate-admissions

I have a B.Tech in Computer Science & Engineering and I want to apply for statistics gradschool. My interest is in stochastic calculus. I'm from india and I have limited exposure to statistics. I have a work experience of 3 years in software development.

Will I get rejected from decent level schools ? What should I do to improve my chances ?

Comment: Why do you want to apply for statistics in a grad school when you think you have little exposure to statistics? What do you think you can offer? If you clarify this, we can help better

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on which country you want to apply for the Grad School. In Japan, you have a very Math oriented entrance examination for the Math department, and is usually the most important factor that decides whether you get in or not.

In USA, the educational system is different, since Undergrad education is often not oriented to a specific area, and you have a good chance as long as you get a high GRE score and have a good set of Recommendation letters (preferably from the Dean of your Univ. if you are not from the US).

As an example, take a look at Stanford's admission requirements:

[International Academic Credentials](http://studentaffairs.stanford.edu/gradadmissions/applying/international)

For India, you do need some kind of engineering background, but other countries like Japan, can in theory apply as long as they have finished an undergrad regardless the discipline.

Bear in mind though, that a PhD in statistics has a hefty load of subjects that assume that you have some mastery on math and advanced math(which, to be honest, the GRE does not cover). So you might have to throw in some hours just to level even with the rest of the students that have math undergrads.

Comment: You're right that good enough recommendation letters would make a big difference in the US, but I think it would be extremely difficult to get such letters with only a limited exposure to statistics.  (Letters that aren't from statisticians or people in closely related fields will count for little.)